# Integral between $-\pi$ and $\pi$

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

How can I show that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin (mt) \sin (nt) {dt}=\begin{cases}\ 0 \mbox{ if } m \neq n\\ \pi \mbox{ if } m=n \end{cases}$.

I want to prove the above property by expressing sinAsinB as a sum of complex exponentials using Euler's formulas.

Thank you

Comment: I added a complete solution using Euler's formula at http://math.stackexchange.com/a/346710/4583

Answer (score 3):

You use $\sin(mt)=\frac {\exp(imt)-\exp(-imt)}{2i}$ and the same for $n$.  When you multiply them you will still have all terms periodic in $t$ and integrating to zero unless $m=n$

Comment: There's a shortcut to avoid part of the computations : write $\int \sin(nx) \sin(mx) dx = \textrm{Im} \left(\int \sin(nx) e^{imx} dx\right) = \frac{1}{2}\textrm{Re} \left(\int (e^{i(m-n)x} - e^{i(m+n)x}) dx\right)$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Use Euler's formula and note that if $\int A+Bi = 0$ then $\int A = \int B = 0$

EDIT: Also, [Show that $\displaystyle\int_{-\pi}^\pi\sin mx\sin nx d x=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }m\neq n,\\\pi&\text{if }m=n\end{cases}$ using integration by parts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/327110/show-that-displaystyle-int-pi-pi-sin-mx-sin-nx-d-x-begincases0-texti)