# Why $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^n(a_k\cos kx+\beta_k\sin kx))(\cos mx) \mathop{dx}=a_m\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos^2 mx\mathop{dx}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Why is this true?

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^n(a_k\cos kx+\beta_k\sin kx))(\cos mx) \mathop{dx}=a_m\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos^2 mx\mathop{dx}$$

I get that $\sin m\pi x$ for $m\in\mathbb{N}$ will equal $0$, so that might be the reason why somehow the sine terms disappear but there's no $\sin \pi m x$, there's only $\sin mx$, so I'm confused why the terms vanish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because those integrals actually evaluate to $0$. Seeing the sine terms is much easier than the cosine terms. Consider
$$ \int_{-\pi}^\pi \sin kx \cos mxdx.$$
Notice that $\sin kx$ is an odd function and $\cos mx$ is an even function, so their product is odd. An odd function integrated over a region $[-A, A]$ will always be $0$. So these sine terms simply do not contribute.

Similarly,
$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos kx \cos mx dx$$
is zero unless $k = m$. There are a variety of ways to show this. For inspiration, you might look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/327121/9754) to a very related question.

*Aside*: From a higher perspective, we might say that $\{\sin nx, \cos mx\}$ form a basis for a certain Hilbert space of functions. Or we might think of this as being related to the Stone-Weierstrass theorem.